# How to find GWS market place app installed OUs

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace, gws

I have a Google Workspace marketplace app that is only GWS admin instalable(not individually installed). I need to find the OU(organization units) list that this app is installed in customer tenant using a GWS API.
I will have customer information as admin email.
Is it possible to find the installed OUs from a GWS API call?